VeeValidate with Autocomplete form vue
I have an issue with autocomplete and vee-validate. When I type and select a suggestion, only the text I typed is detected, not the one I selected from the suggestions. How can I ensure that the selected suggestion updates correctly? Also, when I submit the form, only the text I typed is detected.
For example, I typed "F" and then chose the suggestion "Futsal". The validation is triggered with the error:

String must contain at least 2 character(s)

even though the visual input has already changed to "Futsal".
Here’s my code:
     <FormField v-slot="{ field, componentField }" name="title">
        <FormItem>
          <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Title" v-bind="componentField" v-model="field.value" @input="handleTitleInput(field.value)" autocomplete="off" />
            <ul v-if="TitleFiltered.length > 0" class="absolute z-10 bg-white border border-gray-200 w-full text-sm">
              <li v-for="(suggestion, index) in TitleFiltered" :key="index"
                @click="handleTitleSelect(suggestion, field)"
                class="px-3 py-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200 last:border-none">
                {{ suggestion }}
              </li>
            </ul>
            
          </FormControl>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      </FormField>

and here's my script
const titleSuggestions = ref<string[]>(['futsal', 'football', 'volley', 'tennis', 'badminton']); // Menggunakan ref untuk menjadikan reaktif
const TitleFiltered = ref<string[]>([]);

function handleTitleInput(inputValue: string) {
  TitleFiltered.value = inputValue.length > 0
    ? titleSuggestions.value.filter((suggestion) =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
      )
    : [];
}
function handleTitleSelect(suggestion: string, field: any) {
  field.value = suggestion; // Update input field dengan saran yang dipilih
  TitleFiltered.value = [];  // Kosongkan daftar saran setelah dipilih
  form.validateField('title');  // Validasi field title setelah pemilihan
}

